# create new array of object with keys from data, base on array of object with condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object, reduce

```js
const October = [
  {
    event_category: 'EVENT',
    date: '2022-10-02',
    detail: 'event',
  },
  {
    event_category: 'TASK',
    date: '2022-10-03',
    detail: 'task',
  },
  {
    event_category: 'EVENT',
    date: '2022-10-04',
    detail: 'event 1',
  },
  {
    event_category: 'TASK',
    date: '2022-10-04',
    detail: 'task 1',
  },
  {
    event_category: 'TASK',
    date: '2022-10-04',
    detail: 'task 2',
  },
];
```

is there a method with map or reduce to create new array of object like this.
i have try method with object assign etc.. cant solve it.

the result i want.

```
const newOct = [
  {
    '2022-10-02': {
      event_category: 'EVENT',
      date: '2022-10-02',
    },
    '2022-10-03': {
      event_category: 'TASK',
      date: '2022-10-03',
    },
    '2022-10-04': {
      event_category: 'TASK_EVENT',
      date: '2022-10-04',
    },
  },
];
```

Comment: from where are you getting ```October``` array ?

Comment: @SrushtiShah i just made it for example, is that really matter..?

Comment: yes If you are fetching from database then it would be easier

Comment: ya its fetching from API and i got hundreds of list like that, thats why made it simple. ty so much for your answer. i didnt know the different if it fetching from API so it be easier.

Comment: @mrbig ... The OP might have a look at two other approaches (both based on `reduce` and `map` respectively `forEach` as requested) provided by a late answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You achieve it by using following code

```js
const October = [
    {
        event_category: 'EVENT',
        date: '2022-10-02',
        detail: 'event',
    },
    {
        event_category: 'TASK',
        date: '2022-10-03',
        detail: 'task',
    },
    {
        event_category: 'EVENT',
        date: '2022-10-04',
        detail: 'event 1',
    },
    {
        event_category: 'TASK',
        date: '2022-10-04',
        detail: 'task 1',
    },
    {
        event_category: 'TASK',
        date: '2022-10-04',
        detail: 'task 2',
    },
];

function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

let newOct = [{}];
let dates = October.map(item => item.date);
dates = dates.filter(onlyUnique);

for (let date of dates) {
    let event_category = ''; 
    for (let item of October) {
        if (item.date === date) {
            event_category = event_category ? event_category.includes(item.event_category) ? event_category : event_category + "_" + item.event_category : item.event_category;
        }
    }
    newOct[0][date] = { event_category, date };
}
console.log('newOct: ', newOct);
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP's problem could be solved by ...

1. either a two-folded approach of both, a simple [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and a simple [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ping task
2. or by a single, but slightly more complex, `reduce` task.

**As for *1)* ...**

- one firstly would `reduce` the provided array into an object where the keys are the unique `date`s and the referred item's `event_category` is an array which contains every date related `event_category` value/name. The reducer-function then is as simple as ...

  ```
  function createAndAggregateDateBasedCategoryList(
    result, { event_category, date }
  ) {
    // - create and/or access the date-based category-item ...
    (result[date] ??= {
      event_category: [],
      date,
    })
    // ... and push the current category-name
    //     into the category-list.
    .event_category
    .push(event_category);

    return result;
  }
  ```
- secondly, within a `map`ping task, one would concatenate each final `event_category` value from the array's unique category-names. The related function would look like that ...

  ```
  function concatUniqueCategoryNames({ event_category, ...rest }) {
    return {
      event_category: [...new Set(event_category)].join('_'),
      ...rest,
    };
  }
  ```

The final solution implements/shows the usage of the above two functions ...

```js
function createAndAggregateDateBasedCategoryList(
  result, { event_category, date }
) {
  // - create and/or access the date-based category-item ...
  (result[date] ??= {
    event_category: [],
    date,
  })
  // ... and push the current category-name
  //     into the category-list.
  .event_category
  .push(event_category);

  return result;
}

function concatUniqueCategoryNames({ event_category, ...rest }) {
  return {
    event_category: [...new Set(event_category)].join('_'),
    ...rest,
  };
}

const October = [{
  event_category: 'EVENT',
  date: '2022-10-02',
  detail: 'event',
}, {
  event_category: 'TASK',
  date: '2022-10-03',
  detail: 'task',
}, {
  event_category: 'EVENT',
  date: '2022-10-04',
  detail: 'event 1',
}, {
  event_category: 'TASK',
  date: '2022-10-04',
  detail: 'task 1',
}, {
  event_category: 'TASK',
  date: '2022-10-04',
  detail: 'task 2',
}];

console.log(
  '+++ step 1 +++\n... collected date-based category-names as `event_category` array ...',
  October
    .reduce(createAndAggregateDateBasedCategoryList, {}),
);
console.log(
  '+++ step 2 +++\n... creating the final result from each of the aggregated category-names ...',
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object
      .entries(
        October.reduce(
          createAndAggregateDateBasedCategoryList, {}
        )
      )
      .map(([key, value]) => [
        key, concatUniqueCategoryNames(value)
      ])
    )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

**As for *2)* ...**

One would combine both of the above shown tasks into a single reducer-function, where the creation of the final `event_category` value takes place just at the last reduce-step. The reducer-function and its usage then changes to ...

```js
function createAndAggregateDateBasedCategoryName(
  result, item, idx, arr,
) {
  const { event_category, date } = item;

  // - create and/or access the date based category item.
  const dateBasedItem = (result[date] ??= {
    event_category: [],
    date,
  });
  // - collect the current category-name
  //   within the temporary category-list.
  dateBasedItem
    .event_category
    .push(event_category);

  // - within the last/final reduce step ...
  if (idx >= arr.length - 1) {

    // ... create the final names by concatenating
    //     each temporary list's unique category-names.
    Object
      .values(result)
      .forEach(value =>
        value.event_category = [
          ...new Set(value.event_category)
        ].join('_')
      );
  }
  return result;
}

const October = [{
  event_category: 'EVENT',
  date: '2022-10-02',
  detail: 'event',
}, {
  event_category: 'TASK',
  date: '2022-10-03',
  detail: 'task',
}, {
  event_category: 'EVENT',
  date: '2022-10-04',
  detail: 'event 1',
}, {
  event_category: 'TASK',
  date: '2022-10-04',
  detail: 'task 1',
}, {
  event_category: 'TASK',
  date: '2022-10-04',
  detail: 'task 2',
}];

console.log(
  October
    .reduce(createAndAggregateDateBasedCategoryName, {})
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```